# In a cube, can I just show 1 measure and 2 dimensions, without folders?

Tags: ssas

I'm creating what's supposed to be a very simple cube, with just one measure , and about 7 dimensions.  Each dimension comes from a different table.

It looks like the standard setup is to always have a folder visible for each separate dimension, and also a separate folder for measures.  Normally I can see where that would be desirable, if you have many attributes in one dimension.  However, in this case it's unnecessary and adds complexity.

Is it possible to NOT have separate folders for each dimension?

thanks,
Sylvia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to avoid folders of dimensions but you can combine multiple measures from different measure groups in a new folder and make original ones hidden. That way you can achieve partially but only for a limited case.

Comment: Thanks ebayindir, that's the same conclusion I've been coming to after searching quite a bit.  Disappointing that SSAS doesn't have this option.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your client is for the cubes. 
You see , if you look at things through mgmt studio, or through bids or through excel.. .each will display the dims and measure groups \ measures in their own way. Then there are other tools like old proclarity and performance point or tableau or reporting services which allow more flexibility . 
Im guessing you're not using Excel as your front end , as it doesnt have folders as such. Althought the various hierarchies within a dim are grouped together under the dimension. And each measure group lists its own measures grouped together.

Look at the excel layout and see.

aamer

Comment: Thanks Aamer, these details are helpful.